# Have problem with input(using JSON) in file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

How can I input information in json file with commas between values?

```py
import json
class Calculation():
    """The Program class(ALL)"""
    def __init__(self,money_earned = 0,money_spended = 0):
        self.money_earned = money_earned
        self.money_spended = money_spended

    def m_s(self):
        """input daily spend to file"""
        self.money_spended = str(input("How much money you spend today?"))
        print(self.money_spended)
        file = "data_txt_cat/spend.json"
        with open(file,"a") as f_obj:
            json.dump(self.money_spended,f_obj)

    def m_e(self):
        """input daily earn to file"""
        self.money_earned = input("How much money earned today? ")
        print(self.money_earned)
        file = "data_txt_cat/earn.json"
        with open(file, "a") as f_obj:
            json.dump(self.money_earned, f_obj)

spend = Calculation()
spend.m_s()
spend.m_e()
```

Currently this writes a file with `"11""12"` in it from that input, rather than JSON output

[image: output file information]

Comment: Hello! I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11082165)

Comment: Note that JSON is a closed format – it is intended to write *complete* data chunks. Your current result ``"11""12"`` are two separate JSON data chunks written one after the other.If you need to iteratively append/extend data, other formats such as CSV are more suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're writing a json object with just a single value, rather than really a json structure

Try putting your inputs into a dictionary or list and adding a newline

Additionally, if you're not making some sort of key-value mapping, consider if you're really using JSON at all

---

You may find it convenient to use a dictionary `.update()` method

```py
import json

earned = {
    "value": []  # this is the list being appended to
}
try:
    with open("whatever.json", "r") as fh:  # open for reading and writing
        earned.update(json.load(fh)) 
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("warning: no starting file")

with open("whatever.json", 'w') as fh:  # NOTE clobbers - consider backup and swap
    earned["value"].append(input("How much money earned today?: "))
    json.dump(earned, fh)  # rewrite file
```